# Find entities for specific user through multiple tables in Django Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I searched through stackoverflow about this particular scenario, but could not find a concrete answer, so i'm posting this.

So my problem is that i need to display specific records to a specific user in Django Admin. I'm aware that i can get the concrete logged in user through the `get_queryset` method extracting it from the `request` object. But the issue is i need to look through 6 tables to get to the information about the user of the recommendations so i could know which recommendation to display to him.

For example, if the records i need to display come from a `Recommendation` table, it has a reference to `TableA`, which has a reference to `TableB` .... which has a reference to `TableF` which has a reference to the `User`.

I'm aware i could do this by executing a plain SQL query with multiple joins, but my guess is that there must be a pythonic or Django sophisticated solution to this. But i may be wrong.

The model is unfortunately not in my control, nor i can change it, so i'm left to work with the state of the model that there is.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Unfortunately, i can't share details of it, but i can share the general look of it. So i think this should be enough to have a picture of my problem.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TableF(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class TableE(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    tableF = models.ForeignKey(TableF, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class TableC(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    tableEs = models.ManyToManyField(TableE, through='TableD')


class TableD(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    tableC = models.ForeignKey(TableC, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tableE = models.ForeignKey(TableE, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class TableA(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    tableCs = models.ManyToManyField(TableC, through='TableB')


class TableB(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    tableA = models.ForeignKey(TableA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tableC = models.ForeignKey(TableC, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Recommendation(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    tableA = models.ForeignKey(TableA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can you post the model and the information you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a middleware to include de user to the thread locals and catch this user from get_queryset in the model manager.

```
from threading import local


_thread_locals = local()


def get_current_user():
    return getattr(_thread_locals, 'user', None)


class ThreadLocals(object):
    @staticmethod
    def process_request(request):
        _thread_locals.user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
```

in the settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'path.to.file.ThreadLocals',
]
```

```
from your.path import get_current_user


class TableFManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(creator=get_current_user())


class TableF(models.Model):
    information = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = TableFManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

another less invasive option could be to rewrite the get_queryset in the admin class. there you already have the user in the request

Comment: Not sure if you understood the question, or maybe i'm not understanding your solution. I don't have a problem in getting the current logged in user. I have a problem in the way that i need to display the recommendations from the logged in user, and not all recommendations from everyone. To know which recommendation comes from which user, i need to join all the way through TableF to know if i can display a recommendation to him.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_rec_user(user):
    tes = TableE.objects.filter(tableF__in=TableF.objects.filter(user=user))
    aes = TableB.objects.filter(tableE__in=tes).values_list('tableA_id', flat=True)
    return Recommendation.objects.filter(
        tableA__in=TableA.objects.filter(id__in=aes)
    )
```